# Using Class Modules in Excel VBA to Store and Compare Values of An Array When it Changes

Tags: excel, vba

I chanced upon an answer to a previous post on the topic above. I have tried out the code recommended by Radek (as per the link provided below) and it works.

I am wondering if someone could explain to me how to code works, i.e. how the **MyIniVal** and **MyRange** does not have the same value since the **Initialize_MySheet** procedure sets their value to be the same?

Much thanks in advance!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26738652/4814794

The code is:

Class module called "Class1":

```
Public WithEvents MySheet As Worksheet
Public MyRange As Range
Public MyIniVal As Variant

Public Sub Initialize_MySheet(Sh As Worksheet, Ran As Range)
    Set MySheet = Sh
    Set MyRange = Ran
    MyIniVal = Ran.Value
End Sub
Private Sub MySheet_Calculate()

If MyRange.Value <> MyIniVal Then
    Debug.Print MyRange.Address & " was changed from " & MyIniVal & " to " & MyRange.Value
    StartClass
End If

End Sub
```

and in a normal module:

```
Dim MyClass As Class1

Sub StartClass()
Set MyClass = Nothing
Set MyClass = New Class1
MyClass.Initialize_MySheet ActiveSheet, Range("A2")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

MyIniVal stores the **value** of the cell at the time it is passed to the Initialize_MySheet procedure.
MyRange stores a **reference** to the cell on the worksheet and will update as the cell value changes.

Edit - it is conceivable that Ran could hold a reference to multiple cells in which case the code will fail.