# Worksheet_Change setting target range is slow

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel macro used to manage button visibility in Excel in the "Worksheet_Change" function based from another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610631/excel-vba-change-button-visibility-based-on-update-to-adjacent-cell/39612582).

The problem is the although the macro works it makes updating the Excel sheet rather laggy. I have managed to pin down the slowness to a single line:

```
Set rUpdated = Range(Target.Dependents.Address)
```

This sets the range of cells updated to a variable to be iterated through later in the script. If I call a script with just this line I found this is where all the delay is. It seems a rather simple line, but is there a better way to do it?

Full disclosure:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rUpdated As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rCell As Range
    Set rUpdated = Range(Target.Dependents.Address)
    If Not rUpdated Is Nothing Then
        For Each rCell In rUpdated
            If rCell.Column = 1 Then
                'Look at each shape in the sheet and cross-reference with rCell.
                For Each shp In Target.Parent.Shapes
                    If shp.TopLeftCell.Row = rCell.Row Then
                        shp.Visible = (rCell.Value <> "")
                        Exit For 'Exit the loop - the correct button has been found.
                    End If
                Next shp
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Will your referenced cells always be in the same row? If so, it might be quicker to write a custom function which takes address of changed cell and checks the formulas in current row

Comment: No, the referenced cells could be the full height of the spreadsheet. However I only really care about a single row. I just need a better way than calling `Target.Dependents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced that config with the following single line (and companion line):

```
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Shapes("buttonRow" & Target.Row).Visible = (ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value <> "")
```

However to get this to work I first needed to rename all my shapes. I used this function to do that:

```
Function renamebuttons()
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shp.name = "buttonRow" & shp.TopLeftCell.Row
    Next shp
End Function
```

I ran that function once and deleted it. Once done my shapes can now be referred to by name and I no longer incur the delay of cycling through every shape and every target dependent. The delay experienced in the worksheet is now minimal.

Answer (score 0):

So if i understood it correctly you want to make a button visible if the cell in the row as been changed. The only things i can think of to slow it down are, that is has to check many `rCell` or `Shapes`. I dont know what the structure of your document is. So my Idea would be: instead of going through all shapes  every time, i would name them in a pattern that you can identify them with the row they are in so you use the name to address them (i.e `Row2` for the Button in Row `2`).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rUpdated As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim obj As OLEObject

    Set rUpdated = Range(Target.Dependents.Address)
    If Not rUpdated Is Nothing Then
        For Each rCell In rUpdated
            If rCell.Column = 1 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Set obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Row" & rCell.Row)
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    obj.Visible = (rCell.Value <> "")
                End If
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Going through all rCells or Shapes doesn't appear to cause slowness. If I limited the sub to the single line `Set rUpdated = Range(Target.Dependents.Address)`  that is where I get all the slowness. I tested your code and it ran with similar lag.

Comment: When its this line, you should test it in a clean `Workbook` with only a few reference and see if the performance is stil bad. Is there anything else running in the back?

Comment: Tested in a clean workbook with only the cell formulas copied across. Only VBA code is this single line in the worksheet_change macro. Admittedly there could be a lot of dependents as there are a lot of references to other cells in the formulas, but I can't change this as it would break the functionality and purpose of the sheet. For example one formula references 8 cells, and there can be up to 16 cells in total updated on a single cell update. No performance issue with no VBA.