# If cell value is not equal to zero then message box

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this code to automatically pop up a message box when the value of a cell is not equal to zero. This cell depends on the value of cell A minus the value of cell B.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("H60") <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Not Equal zero!!!!"
End If
End Sub
```

However, when the cell H60 is zero, the message box still continues to pop up. Why?

Comment: Change your `MsgBox` temporarily to `MsgBox "Not Equal zero!!!! Is " & Range("H60")`.  I'm guessing that it isn't exactly zero.

Comment: If it's based on the difference of two cells, then why are you checking only one cell? Somehting like `If Range("A1").Value - Range("B1").Value = 0 Then ...` should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

use `.Value2`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("H60").Value2 <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Not Equal zero!!!!"
End If
End Sub
```

I would however recommend you put some sort of test in there to only fire on certain cell changes, you don't want it firing every time anything is changed on the sheet.

You mentioned the cell relies on 2 other cells, you could have your test on those with something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If target.address = "$I$60" or target.address = "$J$60" then
    If Range("H60").Value2 <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not Equal zero!!!!"
    End If
end if
End Sub
```

This will make it only fire if I60 or J60 are what was changed on the sheet, you can obviously change these to other cell references if you need, I assumed your formula is using I60 and J60

Comment: I think `Worksheet_SelectionChange` is fired on every change in the sheet irrespective of what you write inside the `Sub`. The condition you put however runs a certain code inside the condition. Nevertheless the control will has to go till `End Sub` in all cases.

Comment: Yes the event is fired but the check and resulting msgbox will be omitted if it is not those cells that fired it.

Comment: And TBH I would probably use the worksheet_change event, not the worksheet_selectionchange event

Comment: Agree with you on function choice. On the other part I mis-took your answer, my bad.

Comment: The `Target` for `SelectionChange` will be the cell you are selecting, so using a `Target` of the cells that might be changed to ultimately change H60 won't work (because the change to H60 will occur after the selection).

Comment: All good, it is an interesting point you raise though, I mean we could use `If not blah blah then exit sub` which would probably be technically better but for the purpose of this exercise either works :)

Comment: Good Point YowE3K, I have changed my answer to use `Worksheet_change` and I can't think of any scenario where the OP would want the other event, I believe it must have been used by the OP in error.

Comment: There is one scenario - the two cells that are being subtracted could themselves be calculated by a formula.  (But I don't think this resolves the issue - I can't think of a situation where `Value2` will be 0 when `Value` isn't, unless H60 is a date.)

Comment: In which case you would change your test but you would still use the worksheet_change event, not the Worksheet_SelectionChange event.

Comment: :D A lot depends on what those other formulas are - imagine if one of those formulas was a `SUM` of several cells in an external workbook.  Or it could be an `INDIRECT` referencing cells anywhere on the current worksheet.  It starts getting hard to work out which cell needs to have the `Change` event on it.  (But it is definitely better to use `Change` if the root cells that cause the calculation can be determined.)

Comment: I just found an elegant solution to use Worksheet_Change... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388279/how-can-i-run-a-vba-code-each-time-a-cell-get-is-value-changed-by-a-formula @YowE3K

Comment: Not foolproof for `INDIRECT` but at least you can determine if our earmarked range is in the immediate dependency tree of `Target` range passed in through `Worksheet_Change`. @YowE3K

Comment: That's a really nice solution :). Will add to my little bag of tricks for future use ;)

Comment: @DanDonoghue Hi Dan, I tried your recommendations but it could not work for "Range("H60").Value2". This is because cell H60 formula is cell H58 minus cell F58. Cell H58 formula is summation of cell H7 to H57. Cell F58 formula is summation of cell F7 to F57. Any other recommendations? :)

Comment: Hi all users, I have managed to find out the solution. After i round cell H58 and cell F58to 2 decimal places, my original solution works. Thank you for all the comments. :)