# Finding Value in Last Cell and Comparing Data to Run Macro

Tags: excel, vba

*EDIT
Here is what ended up kind of working. The solutions below do not run the AddProj when new row is inserted.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim X As Range
Set X = LastCell 'The X is superflous, you could just use the LastCell variable
    If Sheet5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).Value < X.Value Then
        X.Value = Me.Range("A" & Rows.Count).Value
        AddProj
    End If
End Sub
```

Module 1 contains the following:

```
  Function LastCell() As Range
        With Sheet5
            Set LastCell = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        End With
    End Function
Sub AddProj()

Sheet1.Range("Master").Copy Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End Sub
```

I am trying to read the data in the last cell of a column.
The value of "X" should be the value of this last cell.
I then want "X" to be compared to the number of rows and if the number of rows is less than "X", perform my macro "AddProj".
Once "X" and Column A are the same value, nothing else is to be done.

For some reason, it is not working. 
This code is on the worksheet where I want the comparison to be made.
Please see my code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

X = LastCell

If Sheet5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).Value < Sheet5.Range("X").Value Then
  Sheet5.Range("X").Value = Me.Range("A" & Rows.Count).Value
  AddProj
End If


End Sub

Sub LastCell()
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select

End Sub
```

The "AddProj" is a module that is referenced in the code above (thank you @jsheeran @SJR ACyril for help):

```
Sub AddProj()

Sheet1.Range("Master").Copy Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheet5.Cells(Sheet5.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If Sheet5.Cells(lRow, 1) > lRow Then
    Sheet5.Cells(lRow, 1) = lRow
    AddProj
End If
End Sub
```

X is a variable but you refer to it as `"X"`. Also avoid using `.Select` as it is not necessary and even in this case just does nothing, because first of all a `Sub` cannot return a value and second `.Select` has also no return value. The best way to calculate the last row is this: `Sheet5.Cells(Sheet5.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a slight variation on UPGs great answer.

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If lRow >= Sheet1.Cells(lRow, 1) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else: AddProj
    End If
```

Comment: Neither of your solutions actually ran AddProj to paste the template in Sheet1. See above for what I did.

Comment: I tested the above with mock data according to your description; i.e. If the number of rows is <= to the value in the last cell in the column, then ran the "AddProj" macro. It work perfectly in a workbook module. Yes, neither of these macros will work for you because, i think you should be using Worksheet_Change event, due to your statement "The solutions below do not run the AddPro' when new row is inserted".  Worksheet_Calculate runs when a cells value, that is used in a formula, changed; Thus causing the recalculation of the worksheet. Adding a row may not activate any formulas.

Comment: Check out this SO question, it will help you understand Worksheet_Calculate [Click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388279/how-can-i-run-a-vba-code-each-time-a-cell-get-is-value-changed-by-a-formula)