# combine Worksheet_Calculate and Worksheet_Change excel vba functions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, event-handling

In my worksheet, column `L` value is getting updated through a formula. Whenever `L` column data is changing, I need to run a function which will update `M` and `K` columns. I am using the following code to do that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim Ticker As Worksheet
Dim target As Range, val As Long, LastRaw As Long, i As Long

    Set Ticker = Workbooks("FyersOne.xlsm").Sheets("Ticker")
    
    LastRaw = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set target = Ticker.Range("L2:L" & LastRaw)
    
            If Not Intersect(target, Range("L2")) Is Nothing Then
    
                For i = 2 To LastRaw
    
                    Ticker.Cells(i, "M").Value = Ticker.Cells(i, "J").Value - Ticker.Cells(i, "K").Value
                    Ticker.Cells(i, "K").Value = Ticker.Cells(i, "J").Value
    
                Next i
       
            End If
        
        
    End Sub
```

I need to run the subroutine only on those rows whose `L` column data is updating. But using above code, the procedure is calculating for all the rows.

In my use case the `L` column data will update at different times for each row, so I need run the code only for those rows.

If I use the `Worksheet_Change` handler I can check the rows which are updating in `L` column.  But the problem is `Worksheet_Change` will not trigger because the value is changing through cell formulas.

Also, Excel is becoming slow due to the code running through all the rows each time. Is there any way I can perform this procedure only on those rows where `L` column value is getting updated?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388279/how-can-i-run-a-vba-code-each-time-a-cell-get-is-value-changed-by-a-formula

Comment: Why don't you use formulas for this? Should be possible I think.